# eloquent - checking one attribute for two possibilities

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a users booking session. I want it if it's confirmed, or not confirmed.

```
$sessions = DB::table('online_counselling')->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                                                     ->where('is_confirmed', '0')
                                                     ->orWhere('is_confirmed', '1')
                                                     ->first();
```

It works fine until I get to the orWhere method. It changes the user id completely to get the first user whose session is confirmed. It totally disregards the authenticated user.

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

`Where` always creates a new `AND WHERE` in the query. When you use `orWhere`, it creates a completely new `WHERE` part.

You have to options; combine the `is_confirmed` part:

```
$sessions = DB::table('online_counselling')->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                                                 ->whereIn('is_confirmed', ['0', '1'])
                                                 ->first();
```

Or combine the `Auth::id()` with the other `where`'s:

```
$sessions = DB::table('online_counselling')->where([
                                               ['user_id', Auth::id()],
                                               ['is_confirmed', '0']
                                           ])->orWhere([
                                               ['user_id', Auth::id()],
                                               ['is_confirmed', '1']
                                           ])->first();
```

One thing to consider: If it doesn't matter if `is_confirmed` is `0` or `1`, why query for it at all? Can't you just retrieve the `online_counselling` with the `where('user_id', Auth::id())`?